# ASP.Net Core MVC Update head tag at end of rendering

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I have an ASP.Net Core MVC application, with a default Layout. Some components are built with Vue.js and handled by Vite.

Since there are separate entries, at the moment of rendering the head tag in the _Layouts.cshtml I don't know which script/css files should be included, since the partial views decide which scripts/css should be included. I'm adding the script/css include tags at the end of the body and it's working with a glitch when the browser is rendering the page.

I would like to add the scripts/css include tags in the head tag as well, but I haven't found any solution to update the head tag at the end of the body tag in the _Layouts.cshtml.

I've tried using HTTP2 Push Header functionality, but it still doesn't work.

Do you have any ideas/suggestions on how to achieve this?

**Edit**:
The scripts/css that should be added are stored by partial views in a HttpContext feature. This feature doesn't have the list of scripts/css to include when the head tag is rendered.

Comment: Move your `@await RenderSectionAsync("Scripts", required: false)` to inside the `<head>` in your _Layout.html

Comment: I have updated my question with some additional information.

Comment: If you can't change anything then there's nothing you can change.

Comment: Options 1) Add a second partial, eg if you have `<partial name="MyPartial">`  then add `<partial name="MyPartialScripts">` and load the scripts in that partial and put it in the `<head>`. 2) hide all the content (maybe show a "loading" icon/image/spinner) then show the content when your scripts have finished parsing 3) just put all the partial's scripts in the _layout/head on every page - modern browsers cached the *parsed* js - this would be a slower initial hit, but after will load much quicker

Comment: Pages are rendered as a *stream* - you can't go back and add something that's already been rendered.   think of it as `html += new_html` for each partial/html node.